# MySQL JDBC compression in transit

Tags: mysql, compression, jdbc

Good morning,

I am looking to set my application connection to MySQL to compress data **in transit**.
I read MySQL doc. but it's not cleat to me if I need to do something on the client side, on the server side, or if even it's possible. I know that mysql,mysqldump, etc clients can compress data in transit. But again, not clear for an application that use MySQL.

I found this config, but again, not sure if it apply to all connections types.

```
[mysqld]
protocol_compression_algorithms=zstd,uncompressed
```

EDIT: I am looking for MySQL 5.7 and 8.x

Comment: Did you read [the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/connection-compression-control.html)?

Comment: I did, but as I stated, it's not clear to me if it's support it outside than when using mysql client. What I am looking for is for a JDBC connection string.

Comment: Normal usage of a database does not need to shovel so much data that compression would matter.

Comment: When you pay the network on usage, it does.

Answer (score 1):

ok. It seem JDBC connection string only need this value.

```
useCompression=true
```

and config set on server side like I posted in my initial question

As a FYI. If you use MySQL in the cloud, like in Google cloud, only the client part is required as the server is already ready to accept compress connection. This is not specified in the MySQL website doc. Most probably is somewhere deep in Google doc.

Comment: How did you verify that this indeed enables compression? I still can't find documentation on the compression related options.